# which function calculate the price again when any item is removed from cart in magento

Tags: function, magento

which function calculate the price again when any item is removed from cart in Magento

please tell me function name and location in file

Comment: Try traversing the code... We are here for problems, not as a wiki...

Comment: if you don't know ,  ignore my question.i just asked for function name not for whole code

Comment: I actually know the answer... But your question is something you can deduce yourself.

Comment: may be .. but actually  i posted here because I'm coding while running that i asked ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

Find deleteAction()

Now what actually it does..
it just remove that item from cart and then redirect back to the cart 
now when cart reload again. it shows call items and then there respective price. cart only calculate price of presented items into it